# CSS ::first-letter drop cap ignores $ symbol. Is there a Polyfill?

Tags: javascript, css, polyfills

I'd like to put a custom style on the $ symbol before a price. The easy way:

```
<style>.dropcap { doStuff; }</style>
<p><span class="dropcap">$</span>19.95</p>
```

Problem is that the easy way isn't semantic or accessible. The simple, standards-based approach I'd like to follow is to use `::first-letter {}` like so:

```
<style>p::first-letter { doStuff; }</style>
<p>$19.95</p>
```

That works fine in most browsers, but Firefox interprets the $ symbol as "punctuation" and ignores the CSS rule. Other modern browsers seem to handle this just fine.

Is there a jQuery / JavaScript polyfill or CSS hack that would let me do this the standards-based way and have it still work in Firefox?

**UPDATE:** I found a polyfill that seems to do the trick: [jquery-fancyletter](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-fancyletter/). Was hoping to also find a Modernizr feature detect but can't find one. Tried writing my own and the damned thing always returns false (even in Chrome where the feature is supported). Would anyone be so kind as to let me know what's wrong with my feature detect?

```
Modernizr.addTest('dollarFirstLetter', function() {
return Modernizr.testStyles('#modernizr p:first-letter {margin-right:20px;display:block}', function(elem) {
    window.ptag = document.createElement("p");
    ptag.innerHTML = "$39.95";
    elem.appendChild(ptag);
    return window.getComputedStyle(ptag, ":first-letter").marginRight === "20px";
});
});
```

Comment: I don't know enough about modernizr to tell why it returns `false`. But even if you fix that, it can't work as a test because Firefox will still apply those styles to the space before "$". So instead of checking the styles of `:first-letter`, you should check the text content of `:first-letter`, and AFAIK that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a test for this in Modernizr, but if you really needed to use it, you would want to create an element that matches the selector you are wanting, and then check an attribute. If it is the known value, then it works, and if it is an unknown/unwanted value, then it is unsupported.

For example

```
#test_element {
  font-size: 0
}
#test_element::first-letter {
  font-size: 10px
}
```

with something like the following javascript

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'test_element'
el.innerHTML = '$';
document.body.appendChild(el);
Modernizr.addTest('fullFirstCharacter', el.clientHeight > 0);
document.body.removeChild(el);
```

Modernizr has a [`testStyle`](http://modernizr.com/docs/#teststyles) method that will handle most of this for you, but the above logic is the concept it is using

(note that in order to test the actual computed styles of an element, you need to actually append it to the body, and then later remove it).

@Oriol's way of doing this is what I would highly suggest using, however.

Comment: This is really helpful, @Patrick! I'm trying to apply your method to `testStyle()` but it's returning false positives. If you're well versed in Modernizr, think you could tell me what I'm doing wrong here? http://jsfiddle.net/jonaz/M85zF/

Comment: Happy to help! I led you down the garden path a bit with my example. Modernizr.testStyles adds the styles your setting as an argument in the div of the element, which you are removing when you set the innerHTML equal to '$'. Simple fix though, just `+=` rather than `=`

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you could use

```html
<p data-currency="$">19.95</p>
```

```css
p::before {
    content: attr(data-currency);
    doStuff;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without any modification to the html? I'd imagine there must be a way to detect the scope of this selector and then use yepnope / Modernizr to load a polyfill. I found a polyfill (https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-fancyletter/), just can't figure out how to do the detection...